# Compute the variable importance scores for a specific class using R

Tags: r, dataframe, machine-learning, classification, caret

I have a binary classification problem where the target variable is either "benign" and "malignant". I have trained the model using the caret package, and I want to find the most important variables for the "malignant" class. I used `varImp` to find the important variables. How can I get these variables into a dataframe, that also includes their importance scores?

My attempt is below:

```
library(caret)
library(MASS)
data("biopsy")
biopsy$ID<-NULL
names(biopsy)<-c('clump thickness','uniformity cell size','uniformity cell shape',
                 'marginal adhesion','single epithelial cell size','bare nuclei',
                 'bland chromatin','normal nuclei','mitosis','class')

sum(is.na(biopsy))
biopsy<-na.omit(biopsy)
sum(is.na(biopsy))
head(biopsy,5)

set.seed(123)
inTraining <- createDataPartition(biopsy$class, p = .75, list = FALSE)
training <- biopsy[ inTraining,]
testing  <- biopsy[-inTraining,]



control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10,repeats = 5, verboseIter = F, classProbs = T)

training<- as.data.frame(unclass(training),                     
                         stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

testing <- as.data.frame(unclass(testing),                     
                         stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

models<-c("knn","rf")
results_table <- data.frame(models = models, stringsAsFactors = F)

for (i in models){
  model_train <- train(class~., data = training, method = i,
                       trControl= control, metric = "Accuracy")
  assign("fit", model_train)
  predictions <- predict(model_train, newdata = testing)
  table_mat<-table(testing$class, predictions)
  accuracy<-sum(diag(table_mat))/sum(table_mat)
  precision_ <-posPredValue(predictions, testing$class)
  recall_ <- sensitivity(predictions, testing$class)
  f1 <- (2*precision_ * recall_) / (precision_ + recall_)
  
  # put that in the results table
  results_table[results_table$models %in% i, "Precision"] <- precision_
  results_table[results_table$models %in% i, "Recall"] <- recall_
  results_table[results_table$models %in% i, "F1score"] <- f1
  results_table[results_table$models %in% i, "Accuracy"] <- accuracy
  
}

# Compute the variable importance scores for the sensitive class
var_imp_sens <- varImp(model_train, useModel = FALSE, scale = FALSE, test = testing, class = "malignant")
print(var_imp_sens)
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible code and data using `dput`?

Comment: @Quinten I do not know what dput is but I will edit the post and share my code

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the `importance` of your object and use the `rownames_to_column` to make the row names a column to have a dataframe like this:

```r
library(caret)
library(MASS)

var_imp_sens <- varImp(model_train, useModel = FALSE, scale = FALSE, test = testing, class = "malignant")
library(tibble)
df <- rownames_to_column(var_imp_sens$importance, "Variable")
df
                     Variable    benign malignant
1             clump.thickness 0.9098015 0.9098015
2        uniformity.cell.size 0.9767267 0.9767267
3       uniformity.cell.shape 0.9776693 0.9776693
4           marginal.adhesion 0.8964631 0.8964631
5 single.epithelial.cell.size 0.9256006 0.9256006
6                 bare.nuclei 0.9457624 0.9457624
7             bland.chromatin 0.9490824 0.9490824
8               normal.nuclei 0.8906823 0.8906823
9                     mitosis 0.7078996 0.7078996
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>